# Anystretch.js with ResponsiveSlides.js not sizing images correctly in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow, fullscreen

Using [anystretch.js](http://goo.gl/qFCtH) to achieve fullscreen images within a div along with [responsiveslides.js](http://goo.gl/nZ5h4) to present the images as a slideshow. 
Everything works as advertised on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Example:
http://danausllc.com/test/

However, on IE9 and earlier, when advancing to the next slide, IE resizes the image down to actual size instead of keeping the image at full screen coverage.

Because of my lack of js knowledge, I'm not exactly sure how to fix. Please help!

I already looked into using backstretch.js instead, but I needed other options. There are other fullscreen slideshow plugin alternatives I looked into, but most of them were overkill for my purpose.

Comment: Can you include relevant source code in your question? It will be easier for us to help you.